# Image of a Directed System under a Contravariant Functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I'm trying to better understand stalks of sheaves, but my question here is mostly categorical.

Let $X$ be a topological space, $p \in X$, and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf on $X$ (into some concrete category). In defining a stalk, we consider the directed system of open neighborhoods of a point $p$ in a space $X$, with the morphisms being inclusions. Then we apply $\mathcal{F}$ to this directed system. On the wikipedia page on direct limits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit), they give this as an example, and they say that we get an "associated directed system" $(\mathcal{F}(U), r^V_U)$ where $r^V_U$ are the restriction maps.

Here's my question. If we have a directed system $(A_i, f^j_i)$ where $f^j_i:A_i \to A_j$ for $i \le j$, and we apply a contravariant functor $\mathcal{F}$, we get $(\mathcal{F}(A_i), \mathcal{F}(f^j_i))$ where $\mathcal{F}(f^j_i):A_j \to A_i$ for $i \le j$. How is the output a directed system? It looks more like an inversely directed system to me. Do we reverse the ordering on our indexing set or something like that?

Comment: Note that Wikipedia uses a covariant functor.

Comment: @Arnaud On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics), wikipedia defines a (pre)sheaf as a contravariant functor (in the section Formal Definitions - Presheaves).

Comment: I meant that Wikipedia uses a covariant functor to define direct limits.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that's relevant, can you explain?

Comment: A contravariant functor is the same thing as a covariant one on the opposite category. Here the directed system is not the category of open neighborhood you describe, but rather its opposite. So your presheaf is covariant on the directed system we are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You are right ; if $\mathcal{F}$ is a contravariant, then the image of a directed system will be inversely directed (or codirected). If you want the image of your directed system to be a directed system, you need to use a covariant functor.

What happens is that in the case of a topological space $X$ and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, the open neighborhoods of $p$ form a directed system under *reversed* inclusion. So $U\leq V$ means in fact that $V\subset U$! So your sheaf, being a contravariant functor on the category of open subsets of $X$, actually becomes a *covariant* functor on the directed system considered, which is why $(\mathcal{F}(A_i), \mathcal{F}(f^j_i))$ is really a directed system.